# How to get all values in Cursor

Tags: android, cursor

I used Cursor in a class extends BaseAdapter,

```
class NewDefinedAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Cursor cursorTitle;
    private TextView title;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private LinearLayout layout;

    public NewDefinedAdapter(Context text, Cursor cursor) {
        cursorTitle = cursor;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(text);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return cursorTitle.getCount();
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        layout = (LinearLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.title_list, null);
        title = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(cursorTitle.getString(0));
        return layout;
    }
}
```

And I call this class like this:

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
view.setAdapter(new NewDefinedAdapter(this, cursor));
```

The cursor.getCount() = 10, but finnaly, I get 10 same result. After I add cursor.MoveToNext(), the program run exception:

```
layout = (LinearLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.title_list, null);
title = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.title);
title.setText(cursorTitle.getString(0));
cursorTitle.moveToNext();
return layout;
```

Exception info:

```
04-07 14:27:28.565: D/AndroidRuntime(26155): Shutting down VM
04-07 14:27:28.565: W/dalvikvm(26155): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-07 14:27:28.575: E/AndroidRuntime(26155): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-07 14:27:28.575: E/AndroidRuntime(26155): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 10
04-07 14:27:28.575: E/AndroidRuntime(26155):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
```

So, what should I get all values in cursor, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `moveToPosition()`:

```
//...
layout = (LinearLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.title_list, null);
title = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.title);
cursorTitle.moveToPosition(position);
title.setText(cursorTitle.getString(0));
//...
```

Comment: yeah, it can work now, but I have a question: if "position" is auto-increment, what's the difference between moveToNext() and moveToPosition(position)

Comment: @Jake `moveToPosition()` will position the cursor based on the row position in the `ListView` so you'll never get past the `Cursor` bounds. With `moveToNext()` you're moving the `Cursor` foward each time the `getView()`(and I think the method is called even before any rows need to be shown in the `ListView`) method will be called and you get out of the `Cursor` limits.